# ngMaterial throwing Error: [$injector:modulerr]

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-material, angularjs-module, angularjs-injector

I am using ngMateril for custom dialog. But I am getting error as  Error: [$injector:modulerr]. I am not able to figure out the error. Any help would be appreciated.

**External scripts in my HTML code**

```js
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.15/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.0/angular-material.min.js"></script>
```

```html
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app', ['ui.router'],['ngMaterial'])
        .config(config)
        .run(run);

    function config($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider)   {
        // default route
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");

        $stateProvider
            .state('home', {
                url: '/',
                templateUrl: 'home/index.html',
                controller: 'Home.IndexController',
                controllerAs: 'vm',
                data: { activeTab: 'home' }
            })
            .state('account', {
                url: '/account',
                templateUrl: 'account/index.html',
                controller: 'Account.IndexController',
                controllerAs: 'vm',
                data: { activeTab: 'account' }
            });
    }
 })();
```

[image]

Comment: as i mentioned in the answer below you are missing the references, check the sample link attached

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure your module slightly differently:

```
.module('app', ['ui.router', 'ngMaterial'])
```

Comment: still getting the same error Error: [$injector:modulerr]

Comment: What's the page it brings you too when you click on the error in the console?

Comment: @Abhinay since you are importing CDN scripts, remove `.min` from `angular.min.js` and try to read the error again, it might show you more info

Comment: @AlekseySolovey: I missed to import angular.animate and angular.aria.....but after fixing this error I am getting new error :Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $$asyncCallbackProvider <- $$asyncCallback <- $animate <- $compile

Comment: @Abhinay their versions need to align (be the same). In fact you should consider using the latest versions of everything. I believe AngularJS should be 1.6.8

Comment: Making the versions align worked for me. Thank you @AlekseySolovey

Answer (score 1):

Order of dependencies should be separated by comma,

```
.module('app', ['ui.router', 'ngMaterial'])
```

Also you are missing the references for ng-area and ng-animate. Check the following answer

[angular material design ui router not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39434779/angular-material-design-ui-router-not-working)